# "Butt in line" vs "cut in line" vs "bud in line"?

Tags: phrases, idioms

What's the proper term to use if you want to talk about trying to move up in the lineup or switch up?

Comment: "Cut the queue" would be most natural to my BrE ear.

Comment: AmE-speakers say "butt in line" and "cut in line" for the same action - to step in front of someone else in line, instead of joining the line at the end.  For butt vs. bud, "Butt in" is the expression, not "bud in".

Comment: @badroit: I think your BrE ear has been corrupted by exposure to AmE. Statistically speaking, ***jump** the queue* is [far more common on both sides of the pond](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cut+the+queue%2Cjump+the+queue&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccut%20the%20queue%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjump%20the%20queue%3B%2Cc0), but you'll note that ***cut*** does actually plot on the AmE corpus in that link. It totally flatlines if you switch to the BrE corpus - I'd say because it's basically a relatively rare AmE variant.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, interesting! **Jump the queue** also sounds natural to me (though it didn't occur to me at first).

Comment: badroit, "cut the queue" is not exactly common in BrE. I had not heard of it until now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As badroit notes, *queue* is more common in British Engish whereas *line* is more common in American English in non-technical settings.

A queue-jumper *cuts* in line, in which *cut* may be interpreted as the sense of trimming or dividing depending on whom you ask; Merriam-Webster lists this sense as a separate meaning:

> **[cut](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cut)**: *intransitive verb* 5.  to advance by skipping or bypassing another. *cut to the front of the line*

To *[butt in](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/butt%20in)* is to *intrude*. In queueing cultures, cutting in line would be rather rude, and could be described as *butting in* into line, especially if one is literally physically *[butting](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/butt)*, i.e. thrusting or pushing headfirst.

*Bud in* is probably an [eggcorn](http://eggcorns.lascribe.net/) for *butt in*.

Comment: Note that *bud in* and *butt in* are pronounced nearly exactly the same in AmE.

Comment: And *butt in line* is an idiom in AmE; it almost never means physically *butting*; that would probably be called *shoving* or *pushing*.

Comment: I don't hear *butt in line* very often (maybe we're too polite in Washington? hah), but weirdly, I see *budge in line* appearing all over the place. Yay internetz.

Comment: I grew up in Washington DC and heard it all the time at school there. Maybe they use a different word now, or maybe you don't hang around enough elementary schools.

Comment: *Jump the line* is a common US usage.

Comment: @PeterShor, there's another meaning of butting that is more applicable here - it also means to interrupt or interfere.  If you're butting in line, you're more likely inserting your in line through rudeness than physical shoving, though I've seen both! lol!

Answer (score 0):

I'm here because I just heard Rainn Wilson say "butt in line" in the movie Super. I grew up in New England and I'd literally never heard that phrase before. We say "cut in line" and have said so since I was growing up in the 60s. Usually, you just say "Hey! No cutting!"

SO, who grew up in New Jersey, says it was always "cut" there as well.

Answer (score 0):

I’m from Upstate New York and we would always say ‘no budging’.