# Definition Required Please

Tags: meaning

Could when people please help me with the following definition?

I would like to know what the technical definition is when an individual uses the language of others or they adapt their language to a particular audience. E.g. When a person uses a word only when with a particular group of people.

Many thanks.

Comment: Like an American saying "bollocks" or "bloody hell" instead of "shit" or "damn" to a British audience?

Comment: @NVZ  Why would an American avoid saying "shit" or "damn" to a British audience?  They are both common British swear words.

Comment: @TrevorD Haha. This could be a better example: [Is it conceivable that President Obama might use the word “queue”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/321044/50044)

Comment: @NVZ Yes, that is a good example!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest **Register Change**:

> We use the term **["register"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/register)** to refer to particular varieties or
>   styles of speaking and writing. Registers vary because the language is
>   used for different purposes, in different contexts and for different audiences.